# How to extract fuzzy knowledge when building a knowledge graph?

Tags: methods, graph, extract, fuzzy, computer-science-theory

I recently have been researching how to extract the fuzzy knowledge when building the knowledge graph, but I currently only know to use some fuzzy mathematics algorithm, but I haven't got a clue, so, any good idea?

By the way, I also want to ask whether ontology construction is included in knowledge extraction?

Comment: I am not sure this question is clear. Can you give an example of what sort of knowledge you want to extract, and what software you propose to use to do this?

Comment: For example, Thomas is very fat, which is a fuzzy knowledge, because the condition is not quantified.
As for the specifics, I didn't understand what my teacher was saying. He just asked me to be responsible for the research.
I want to ask you, is it not necessary to distinguish the extracted knowledge in the knowledge extraction whether it is fuzzy knowledge, but only when the ontology construction is needed?

Comment: OK. Normally I'd advise you to bulk up your question with that information, by editing it. Knowledge graphs is not my area though, so I can't answer it myself. Is this more a Computer Science question, rather than an implementation/programming question? If so, it may be better for [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). I don't post there though, so please read the guidelines before posting. As it stands, it does not seem to be a programming question, so is not on-topic here.